# Export to Excel in Angular2 with data formatting

Tags: angular, typescript, export-to-excel, number-formatting, date-formatting

I have a function for exporting to Excel. I have used `file-saver` and `xlsx` npm packages and it works perfectly. Here is the code where I call `exportAsExcelFile`:

```
this.httpservice.getSales_ByBillNo(this.branchUID, this.billNoUrl, this.fromDate, this.toDate)
                .subscribe((data1: Observable<any>) => {
                    this.billNoResults = data1;
                    this.httpservice.exportAsExcelFile(this.billNoResults,'BillNo', 'DayWiseSalesByTotalReport');
                });
```

Here is the `exportAsExcelFile` function in **Service.ts**:

```
exportAsExcelFile(json: any[],dataOne:string, excelFileName: string): void {

    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { dataOne: worksheet }, SheetNames: [dataOne] };

    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: false, type: 'binary' });

    let buf = new ArrayBuffer(excelBuffer.length);
    let view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i != excelBuffer.length; ++i) view[i] = excelBuffer.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;

    const data: Blob = new Blob([buf], {
        type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });

    saveAs(data, excelFileName + new Date() + EXCEL_EXTENSION)
}
```

The above function works perfect. In the Excel, I have dates and other value columns. Here is the screen shot of it:

[image: Export to Excel]

But I need `BillDate` to be formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`. `Qty` and `Value` should be formatted as decimal, with 2 digits after the decimal point.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I have attached the `json` here.

[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibw6Q.png)

Comment: can you post the `json: any[]` value in your `exportAsExcelFile` method ? you can use moment.js to convert the date format

Comment: @Niladri I have posted the json. I will check how to use moment.js for formatting. Thanks

Comment: i don't see the json in the code

Comment: I am storing the json result in billNoResults and passing that to the ExportAsExcelFile()

Comment: @user9006195 have you got any solution?